# Не могу обратиться к элементу матрицы для добавления её в массив python

Tags: python

```
 # В матрице найти отрицательные элементы, сформировать из них новый массив.
 # Вывести размер полученного массива
 import random as rnd
 import numpy as np

 n = 0
 i = 0
 arr1 = np.matrix([[rnd.randrange(-2, 5), rnd.randrange(-2, 5)],
                  [rnd.randrange(-2, 5), rnd.randrange(-2, 5)]])
 result = []
 for n in range(2):
     for i in range(2):
         if arr1[[n], [i]] < 0:
             result = [result.append(arr1[[n], [i]])]

 print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как говорится "да тут всю систему надо менять!" Правильная работа с `Numpy` будет выглядеть примерно так:

```py
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.random.randint(-2, 5, (2, 2))
print(arr1)

result = arr1[arr1 < 0]
print(*result.shape)
```

Пример вывода:

```
[[-1  1]
 [-1  4]]
2
```

Что касается вашего кода:

- модуль `random` не нужен, вы можете получить случайную матрицу с помощью самого `numpy` гораздо проще и быстрее
- метод `matrix` устарел, используйте универсальный `array`
- в `numpy` циклы обычно не нужны, можно сразу все элементы проверить на нужное условие и выбрать их
- метод списка `append` возвращает `None`, не нужно этот `None` присваивать обратно в список (да и список тут вообще не нужен)